# Eclipse does not start when I run the exe?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I run the Eclipse.exe within the given folder, it will not start. The Eclipse splash screen will appear for a split second then close. There are no errors.

I've tried practically everything. Updating JDK and JRE: I installed JRE 7 and JDK 1.7.0_40. Both 64 bit, and they are both in the (x86) folder. I've tried re-installing them. And re-downloading Eclipse. Same result every time. I've added the VM to the config, still nothing.

I use Windows 7 and the standard Eclipse for Java IDE.

Comment: IF it Windows, Right click on My Computer, Click Manage. It will open the Computer Management, and goto Event Viewer -> Windows Log -> Application, will display the exact error message for unsuccessful Eclipse launch. Can you please update your question with that error code and msg?

Comment: I have same Windows 7, and I have download the same version from http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse.mirror/ And It works just fine. Can you uninstall and install it again?

Comment: Post the log from <workspace>/.metadata/.log, or if you never selected a workspace, look for a *.log in the eclipse directory.

Comment: Just uninstalling Java 8 update 45 made my eclipse work. Thanks @Michael.

Comment: If someone get stuck with problem, check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/47948092/7856586. It so difference from anther solutions and it helps me.

Answer (score 54):

Go to your Workspace folder then go to Metadata > plugins.
Delete everything from this folder. Then it will work.

***Warning:*** This will delete *every configuration* from Eclipse!

Comment: This worked for me. Recently installed a new plugin which apparently fails. Too bad that you can't delete a specific plugin and save some time reinstalling all the ones that actually work.

Comment: The .metadata folder is an area where Eclipse plug-ins can save any information they want to save.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19996319/2362301

Comment: Dont even do that you will be in big trouble

Comment: I tried doing this. It still don't work for me. Just uninstalling Java 8 update 45 made my eclipse work. Thanks @Michael.

Comment: I cut and pasted the .plugin folder outside the .metadata folder, I run eclipse and it worked. Then I closed eclipse pasted back the .plugin folder and run again eclipse without any problem.

Comment: This delets every configuration from Eclipse. You must say this before post

Comment: Please say that this will remove all the configurations from eclipse

Comment: My problem was that i didn't had ecplise installed but still had this folder, this solved it

Answer (score 47):

```
eclipse.exe -clean -clearPersistedState
```

All you have to do is go the dir where your eclipse.exe is there and run the above command

Comment: Tried this and got a error dialog - "The file -clearPersistedState could not be found". Eclipse Neon version

Comment: It's two dashes (SO is not helpful here).

Comment: It worked for me! BUT, insted of "eclipse.exe --clean --clearPersistedState" I tried "eclipse.exe -clean -clearPersistedState" ONLY 1 dash

Comment: This worked!!!!! Never had to do this in Kepler, not sure why I had to do it with Oxygen.

Comment: Worked like charm!!

Comment: I've had to do this in the 2020-06 version.

Comment: Had to do ".\eclipse.exe -clean -clearPersistedState", but Windows Powershell told me about it.

Comment: This worked for me, but my issues was a bit different. My eclipse would hang at the splash screen. The startup progress bar was at about 50% initialized. Ran this and it came up. No need to rebuild my workspace. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

The same thing was happening for me.  All I had to do was uninstalled Java Update 8

Comment: I was unable to view even the eclipse splash screen on Windows 8.1. I had to uninstall Java 8 Update 45 to get eclipse working.

Comment: The same issue happened to me. Just uninstalling Java 8 update 45 made my eclipse work. Thanks @Michael .

Comment: I had to uninstall Java 8 and install Java 7 instead, and it worked, thanks!

Comment: I had to uninstall java 8 and then update the PATH variable to point to java 7. This post helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007611/eclipse-startup-error-jre-jdk-must-be-available Then restart my windows 7 machine for PATH change to take place and eclipse came up

Answer (score 19):

go to : "C:\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench"

if already you save backup file "workbench.xmi" replace it else delete this.

Comment: I tried doing this. It still don't work for me. Just uninstalling Java 8 update 45 made my eclipse work. Thanks @Michael.

Answer (score 12):

This also happened to me. I tried some of the solutions above but couldn't get it done. **What i have to do was reinstall the JRE/JDK** again and it worked!

When i executed the command "java-version" in cmd, i was getting an error trying to load a class and then when i reinstalled JRE/JDK, it worked all good!

Answer (score 7):

I looked online and found a person who had a [similar problem.](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/549071/)

It says on the forum

> "You might need to download JRE 64 bit version"

But again, it depends on what OS you're using as well.

Answer (score 3):

Kindly check the following:

1) Your **eclipse version**,whether it is compatible with what version of java.
Have that.

2)Check the operating system specific **BIT requirements** either 32/64 with eclipse version.

3)Usually java will be installed in ProgramFiles for Java if both OS & Java are 64 bit else it will be in ProgramFiles(x86) if java is 32bit and OS is 64Bit.

4)Last but not least check the **environment variables for Java** whether it meets the requirements of your eclipse version.

Hope this Helps you!

Comment: Yep, my other version of eclipse was 64-bit, so I needed a 32-bit java.

Answer (score 2):

What system you have - 32-bit or 64-bit? You say it was installed into (x86) folder. But normally (x86) is a default for the 32-bit JDK, not for 64-bit JDK. If you used defaults, then it seems that you installed 32-bit JDK instead of 64-bit.

Comment: No, I'm 64 bit. And I have 64 bit JDK and JRE. Which are in both "Program Files" and "Program Files (x86)"

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded 64-bit eclipse not 32-bit?

Comment: No I definitely have 64-bit eclipse. I even tried downloading the 32 bit to see if that worked. But no. I'm positive I have the 64 bit.

Comment: Launch console (cmd.exe), go to your eclipse directory, laucnh eclipse.exe. There may be some exception on some error message in the console. Put it here, then we'll see what to do further.

Answer (score 2):

The actual issue should be with the OS architecture, the JDK (32bit or 64 bit) installed and the eclipse type u installed.

Bring them in sync, things would work completely fine.

Just have a check at the Eventlog as mentioned by @Viji
Ideally u should encounter error like RADAR_PRE_LEAK_64

Answer (score 2):

If its a `Java` version problem, you can edit the `eclipse.ini` file and assign the compatible version to the application through adding these lines:

windows example:

```
-vm
C:\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javaw.exe
```

for more information:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Comment: That worked for me, I believe this was caused by a recent JRE update.

Answer (score 2):

1. Press Win key + X
2. click 'System' link from popup menu
3. click advance setting link (Left panel) in opened 'System setting' window (Control Panel\System and Security\System)
4. Now a window named 'System property' will be open, select 'advance' tab and click on environmental variables
5. Select path variable from 'System Variable' list section. and click edit
6. click new button on newly opened window and paste your Jre folder link(Jre in JDK) click okey , okey , okey
7. re run your program :p

Comment: Todays people press Win-Key and search for "system environment variable" or something similar. You are talking to devleopers not managers ;)

Answer (score 1):

re install your java. First check your OS version.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply uninstall java 8 update 45, it worked for me. Also you might need to delete the metadata of your workspace as I have first deleted the metadata and then uninstalled java 8 update 45.

Comment: This question was asked in 2013 and java 8 was not there then :) . But it might be useful to somebody else but not OP.

Comment: @Robert yes go back to whatever old version of Java at which your Eclipse was working fine.

Comment: Java 7u80 worked for me with Eclipse Juno. Java 8 didn't.

Answer (score 1):

If eclipse (none of them) doesn't launch at all and there's not even an error message, uninstall Java 8 Updater and reinstall Java 8 from scratch, this should work. Have luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Eclipse into a folder without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem happened with me . I started eclipse after many days , but it was not starting.just eclipse window flashing , no error nothing. After many trials , `i just re-installed my jdk` . It worked for me, i think some of my java files were missing or damaged . Try by reinstalling your jdk version it may work as it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything except this. After rigorous trials,Uninstalling java 8 update 25 helped me.

Comment: This worked for me too. I have Eclipse Juno with Android ADT. It simply didn't start until I uninstalled Java 8 and installed Java 7. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

did not have to uninstall Java JDK - just ran installer over my existing install.  Not sure what was wrong but this fixed my issue with Eclipse not starting.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Eclipse mars.  It suddenly over the weekend stopped working and if you ran it from a command window (Windows x64) it would flash up a line or two and then stop.

I installed Eclipse neon yesterday and it worked, but today it stopped working and went wrong in the same way.

Just now I installed the JDK from here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

I installed version 8u101 and then neon started.  I have not changed eclipse.ini (although I had a look at it) nor have I deleted the plugins (I renamed the folder and found that this had no effect).

Hence I think this difficult to work out problem relates to the JDK/JRE.  It would be nice if Eclipse gave a bit more information to go on, but such is life.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue in Eclipse Neon. After trying all these suggestions, it turned out that in my case the problem was improperly configured path variables.

There is a pretty good answer already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation) which explains it, but I'll summarize it in this answer for convenience.

You will need to go into your User Environment Variables panel and modify the following values:

- `JAVA_HOME :` `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102`
- `JDK_HOME  :` `%JAVA_HOME%`
- `JRE_HOME  :` `%JAVA_HOME%\jre`
- `CLASSPATH :` `.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib`
- `PATH      :` `your-unique-entries;%JAVA_HOME%\bin` (make sure that the longish `your-unique-entries` does not contain any other references to another Java installation folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was not having a proper javabin folder in the PATH variable.

Open the PATH variable and make sure it points to a proper JRE bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me.

I was using dual monitor and eclipse opened on my other screen, behind a full-screen window.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by deleting the `.metadata/.lock` file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did see the splash screen hanging at

```
loading org.eclipse.egit.ui
```

So I deleted everything starting with `org.eclipse.egit` within the `eclipse\plugin` folder

[image: Eclipse splash screen hanging]

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling eclipse (newer version) did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be rare but this happens on `windows 10` where the `eclipse.exe` file is located in a sub-folder which has some `UTF-8` folder parent

For example this :

`D:\Personal\Idea\دستیار هوشمند بانکی\eclipse` doesn't work while

`D:\Personal\Idea\Bank AI Assistants\eclipse` works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, moving eclipse to a new fresh machine, I had wrong path of lombok.jar in eclipse.ini

check all eclipse.ini configurations

Answer (score -1):

In System Environment variables , add jdk path in the BEGINNING of the Path

[image].