# What is the .metadata folder in Eclipse workspace?

Tags: eclipse, backup

My "workspace" folder includes a hidden folder called ".metadata". Is it important to backup this folder regularly?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `.metadata` folder is an area where Eclipse plug-ins can save any information they want to save. This will include things like your preference settings, information about the contents of projects and the indices the Java plug-in uses to find classes and methods quickly.

It also includes the `.log` file where Eclipse logs errors.

Exactly what is stored there depends on the plug-ins you have installed (one of my plug-ins has a database in the .metadata) so it is a good idea to back it up (along with the projects).

Comment: I want to put another project in another workspace but my eclipse preferences should be same can I copy the .metadata into the newer eclipse locatrion so that I need not set my java,maven and plugins again?

Comment: @Juke Use File > Export > General > Preferences to export your preferences and File > Import > General > Preferences to import them. There are all sorts of things in the .metadata, copying it is not a  good idea.

Comment: After I import I get file.epf can I copy that in all the different workspaces or should I import that in every workspace?

Comment: @Juke You have to import the epf file in to each workspace