# Eclipse: How to create the log file workspace/.metadata/.log in another folder

Tags: java

I am using Eclipse Version: 3.2.0
Currently, my java workspace is working fine and I am able to see the log file.

My workspace is located in D:\Projects\ICC\Workspace\eclipse-SDK-3.2-win32\eclipse

Because my workspace is located in D:\Projects\ICC\Workspace\eclipse-SDK-3.2-win32\eclipse, 
the .log file is created in D:\Projects\ICC\Workspace\eclipse-SDK-3.2-win32\eclipse\workspace.metadata.log

As per my customer need, I have to create this .log file in windows AppData folder due to there folder access limitations.

I do not know how/where to change the .log file location.

I kindly request to help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the .metadata folder in Eclipse workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19996170/what-is-the-metadata-folder-in-eclipse-workspace)

Comment: Sorry, this post is not duplicate. This post is related to creation of .log file in to Windows AppData folder.

Comment: Where is your workspace located? (as in: what is its full path)

Comment: My workspace is located in D:\Projects\ICC\Workspace\eclipse-SDK-3.2-win32\eclipse